# Nginx permissions with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I am trying to set up wordpress on digitalocean with nginx.  I am running into permissions issues though.  When I upload a file or try to install a plugin I get the cannot create in directory warning.  So I came across the post [Here](https://websiteforstudents.com/fix-file-upload-issues-with-wordpress-running-on-nginx-on-ubuntu/) that says I need to give nginx access to the folder.  So I executed the following:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/folder
sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/folder
```

This works except now I cannot add and delete files with filezilla.  Obviously because the permissions to the folder are no longer with the me the user they are now with www-data.

So my question is what is the correct way to configure nginx to work with wordpress and still allow me to upload and delete files with ftp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using digital ocean droplets you will probably be using sftp access to your server.

Try the following commands in your terminal when logged in.

1. Add your currently logged in user to the www-data group:

   sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER
2. Then change your vhost directory and all files and subdirectories to be owned by www-data group:

   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
3. Set the proper permissions so you can upload files via sftp, manage files via command-line, and upload plugins and media directly in WordPress:

   sudo chmod -R 774 /var/www

Hope this helps

Saskia

Comment: All my plugins deactivated because of this answer